# InverseBindingAdapter - Get original value

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-databinding, material-components-android

I am implementing a custom two way data binding. For the InverseBindingAdapter, I want to get the original value like this example https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/InverseBindingAdapter

Sadly I get an error when I compile

> error: @InverseBindingAdapter getDuration(ButtonToggleGroup, int) takes 2 parameters, but 1 parameters were expected

Bindings.kt

```
@BindingAdapter("durationAttrChanged")
fun setDuration(buttonToggleGroup: ButtonToggleGroup, listener: InverseBindingListener) {
    buttonToggleGroup.addOnButtonCheckedListener { _, buttonId, isChecked ->
        if (isChecked) {
            listener.onChange()
        }
    }
}

@BindingAdapter("duration")
fun setDuration(buttonToggleGroup: ButtonToggleGroup, oldValue: Int?, newValue: Int?) {
    val value = newValue ?: return
    if (oldValue == newValue) return

    // Some code here...
}

@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "duration")
fun getDuration(buttonToggleGroup: ButtonToggleGroup, originalValue: Int?): Int? {
    return // Something
}
```